# Timezone on VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to Create one visualforce page,Query any one record and display Created Date on page in this format mm-dd-yyyy hh : mm using Use Format method, then format the dateTime to required format
Format method is avilable in class DAteTime
Can anyone help me out in this

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="account" extensions="timeZone">

<apex:dataTable style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" value="{!details}" var="a" width="100%" styleClass="tableClass" cellpadding="4" border="1">     

        <apex:column headerValue="Date">
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm}">
                <apex:param value="{!a.CreatedDate}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class timeZone {
public string cd;
        public timeZone(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}
        public list<account> getdetails(){
    list<account> a = [SELECT id,CreatedDate FROM account where name = 'mal'];
   // String strConvertedDate = a.CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', UserInfo.getTimeZone());
    return a;
}   

}
```

Comment: what is issue here?

Comment: the account vich i query has createdtime 12/7/2015 3:10 AM.. but wen i execute dis the output is  12/07/2015,11:10.. which is a different timezone..so i want that on VF page also  the same time should appear

Comment: are your viewing the both dates with same user ?

Comment: @malvika you need to format createdDate based on current user's timezone in  controller

Comment: yes @Ratan correct but am not able to do that.. I have tried using dateTimeValue = System.Now().format('MM/dd/yy HH:mm a', 'PST');//GMT but this is olso not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**: Salesforce store the dateTime value in database in GMT Format. When the dateTime display on standard page. It display in current user's time zone

Use in controller.. use `strConvertedDate` instead `a.CreatedDate`

DateTime format for current user

`CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm', UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID())` 
or

`CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString())`

```
String strConvertedDate = a.CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
```

---

**Edit**

**Controller**

```
public class timeZone {
        public timeZone(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}

        public List<wrapperAccount> getdetails(){

        List<wrapperAccount> lstwrapper = new List<wrapperAccount>();
    for(Account obj: [SELECT id, Name, CreatedDate FROM account]){
        lstwrapper.add(new wrapperAccount(obj));
    }

    return lstwrapper;
}   
    public class wrapperAccount{
        public Account objAccount {get; private set;}
        public String strFormattedDate {get; private set;}
        public wrapperAccount(Account objAccount){
        this.objAccount = objAccount;
        strFormattedDate = objAccount.CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="account" extensions="timeZone">

<apex:dataTable style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" value="{!details}" var="wrap" width="100%" styleClass="tableClass" cellpadding="4" border="1">     

        <apex:column headerValue="Date">
            <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.strFormattedDate}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            <apex:outputText value="{!wrap.objAccount.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I added ..and m getting this error Error: timeZone Compile Error: Variable does not exist: CreatedDate at line 12 column 31

Comment: @malvika you need to format account created date

Comment: I did a.CreatedDate.forma and i get this error Error: timeZone Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Account> at line 6 column 31

Comment: no still the sam issue..time is not matchnig..ex. createdtime 12/7/2015 3:10 AM.. but wen i execute dis the output is 12/07/2015,11:10.. which is a different timezone

Comment: ya I copy pasted your code

Comment: @malvika ohh my miss you need replace `UserInfo.getTimeZone().getDisplayName()` with `UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString()` or `UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID()`

Comment: thanx a ton ratan.. it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

As Ratan said, Salesforce stores the dates in UTC/GMT timezone and returns that in apex and in some places in VisualForce.  If you were to use the value attribute on the column it would do an automatic conversion to the user's locale similar to outputField, inputField, etc.

**Example:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="test" columns="1">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataTitle="poo">
                    <apex:outputLabel>Locale Conversion</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Opportunities}" var="opp">
                        <apex:column value="{!opp.CreatedBy.Name}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!opp.CreatedDate}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!opp.Amount}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>No Locale Conversion</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Opportunities}" var="opp">
                        <apex:column value="{!opp.CreatedBy.Name}"/>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Date">
                            {!opp.CreatedDate}
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column>
                            {!opp.Amount}
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <br/><br/>
        <strong>Locale Conversion</strong>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!Account.Opportunities}" var="opp">
            <apex:column value="{!opp.CreatedBy.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Date" value="{!opp.CreatedDate}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Amount" value="{!opp.Amount}"/>
        </apex:dataTable>

        <br/><br/>
        <strong>No Locale Conversion</strong>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!Account.Opportunities}" var="opp">
            <apex:column value="{!opp.CreatedBy.Name}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="Date">
                {!opp.CreatedDate}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Amount" >
                {!opp.Amount}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Output of example above:**
[image: example output]

If you do need to use a format different from the running user's and find yourself having to do it regularly, I wrote a component a while back to do this easily.  You'll need to pass a timezone string to it though, it doesn't use the user's default.  Ratan's method in the comments on his answer should work fine, but you'll have to expose it in the calling page's controller/extension or modify the component's extension to accept something like "User" and automatically apply it.

You can find it on my blog here:  http://www.cloudywithachanceofcode.com/dateconvert-component/

Here is the source.  If there is enough interest, maybe I'll throw it into GitHub for others to contribute.

**Component "dateConvert.component"**

```
<apex:component access="global" selfClosing="true" controller="dateConvert">
    <apex:attribute name="format" assignTo="{!dateFormat}" access="global" type="String" default="M/d/yyyy h:mm a" description="Format of the datetime field"/>
    <apex:attribute name="field" assignTo="{!dateField}" access="global" type="DateTime" required="true" description="Field to convert"/>
    <apex:attribute name="timezone" assignTo="{!dateTimezone}" access="global" type="String" default="GMT" description="Timezone to convert to"/>

    <apex:outputText value="{!output}"/>
</apex:component>
```

**Component controller class "dateConvert.cls":**

```
public class dateConvert {
    public String dateTimeZone {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime dateField {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String output {
        get {
            return dateField.format(this.dateFormat, this.dateTimeZone);
        }
    }
    public String dateFormat {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```